# Mutate a dynamic column name with conditions using other dynamic column names

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use `dplyr::mutate` to change a dynamic column with conditions using other columns dynamically.

I've got this bit of code:

```
d <- mtcars %>% tibble
fld_name <-  "mpg"
other_fld_name <- "cyl"
d <- d %>% mutate(!!fld_name := ifelse(!!other_fld_name < 5,NA,!!fld_name))
```

which sets mpg to

```
mpg  
   <chr>
 1 mpg  
 2 mpg  
 3 mpg  
 4 mpg  
 5 mpg  
 6 mpg  
 7 mpg  
 8 mpg  
 9 mpg  
10 mpg
```

it seems to select the field on the LHS of assignment operator, but just pastes the field name on the RHS.

Removing the unquotes on the RHS yields the same result.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Unless you won't give a reproducible example, it is hard to tell, but in this one it seems that you have to remove unquote operations inside ifelse, as it directly works on vectors

Comment: okay I'll put an example together for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `get` to retreive column value instead

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- mtcars %>% tibble
fld_name <-  "mpg"
other_fld_name <- "cyl"

d %>% mutate(!!fld_name := ifelse(get(other_fld_name) < 5 ,NA, get(fld_name)))

#> # A tibble: 32 x 11
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#>  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#>  3  NA       4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#>  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#>  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#>  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
#>  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
#>  8  NA       4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#>  9  NA       4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#> 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Wonderful, does exactly what I need. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

We can also use `ensym` function to quote variable name stored as string and unquote it with `!!` like the following:

```
library(rlang)

d <- mtcars %>% tibble
fld_name <-  "mpg"
other_fld_name <- "cyl"

d %>% 
  mutate(!!ensym(fld_name) := ifelse(!!ensym(other_fld_name) < 5, NA, !!ensym(fld_name)))

# A tibble: 32 x 11
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3  NA       4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 8  NA       4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9  NA       4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# ... with 22 more rows
```

Comment: Also, the `en` prefix is mostly used within a function.  outside function, you can simply use `sym`

Answer (score 2):

We could also use `.data`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
    mutate(!! fld_name := case_when(.data[[other_fld_name]] >=5 ~ 
         .data[[fld_name]]))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 32 x 11
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3  NA       4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 8  NA       4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9  NA       4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# … with 22 more rows
```

#### data

```
d <- mtcars %>% 
         as_tibble
fld_name <-  "mpg"
other_fld_name <- "cyl"
```

Comment: @AnoushiravanR `{{}}` work when you pass unquoted (usually inside a function) though it works for the lhs of `:=`

Comment: For strings, it is either `.data` or `!!sym` (outside function) or `!!ensym` - can take both quoted/unquoted